# Using .each() twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script to create a sequence of random numbers, using the values ​​of the array, and applying these numbers into two lists of divs

```
var shuffle = function(v) {
    for (var j, x, i = v.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);
    return v;
};

var randorder = shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]);
var index = 0;

$('.Questions').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('question' + (randorder[index++]));
});

$('.answers').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('answer' + (randorder[index++]));
});
```

The problem is that the script is returning to the class answer the result "answerundefined."

Remembering that both sets must have the same order, to match questions and answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say because I don't know how many `.Questions` and `.answers` you have, but when you see `undefined`, it means you are going outside of the bounds of the `randorder` array. So, you at least need to set index back to zero between the loops:

```
var index = 0;

$('.Questions').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('question' + (randorder[index++]));
});
index = 0;
$('.answers').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('answer' + (randorder[index++]));
});
```

The reason why you need to set index back to 0 is because by the time you are done looping through `.Questions`, index has a value of 20. So, when you loop through `.answers`, index has goes from 20 to 39. You want 0-19, so you need to reset it.

Additionally, you might want to check if you are still in bounds:

```
var randcount = randorder.length;
$('.Questions').each(function() {
    if (randcount > index) {
        $(this).addClass('question' + (randorder[index++]));
    }
});
```

Comment: I have exactly 20 questions, like the array. Just put another index= 0; works for me. But why?

Comment: @user1633525 I added an explanation to my answer. Basically, when you start looping over `.answers`, index has a value of 20, but you want 0, so you have to reset it. The loops do not happen simultaneously.

Comment: @user1633525 And BTW, Beetroot-Beetroot has a nice solution if you want to make some significant changes. Either way should work, but his is very clean and much more maintainable. It builds a randorder array based on the Questions and Answers on the page rather than some constant (20) that you happen to know you want to use at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's will be easier and naturally error tolerant to turn the whole thing on its head and loop through `randorder` (once).

```
var randorder = shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]);
var $questions = $('.Questions');
var $answers = $('.answers');

$.each(randorder, function(i, r) {
    $questions.eq(i).addClass('question' + r);
    $answers.eq(i).addClass('answer' + r);
});
```

Of course you still need to ensure the original `[1, ... 20]` array is the correct length to shuffle all the questions, so it would be better to generate the array automatically in response to the length of the questions/answers collections.

You can do this with a modified version of `shuffle()`, in which the integer sequence is generated before being shuffled (better algorithms no doubt exist).

```
var shuffle = function(n) {
    var v = [];
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
        v.push(i);
    }
    for (var j, x, i = v.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);
    return v;
};

var $questions = $('.Questions'),
    $answers = $('.answers'),
    randorder = shuffle(Math.min($questions.length, $answers.length));//in case questions and answers are different lengths we choose the lower length.

$.each(randorder, function(i, r) {
    $questions.eq(i).addClass('question' + r);
    $answers.eq(i).addClass('answer' + r);
});
```

Note: `shuffle()` returns a shuffled array of integers from zero to n, not 1 to n, which was possibly the cause of the original problem.

Comment: +1 A lot of us just told him how to fix his problem, but you showed him how to make it much more robust and maintainable.

Comment: @lbstr, thank you but I may have made a small mistake. See my alternative suggestion above. What do you think?

Comment: yes your edit is correct. `i` is the index and `r` is the value.

Comment: Thanks @lbstr, I've rolled that change into the answer (in 2 places).

Answer (score 0):

Index was for questions and after increment you may get the undefined only for answer $.each. Check index values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = 0;

// Runs 20 times, index starts at = 0
$('.Questions').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('question' + (randorder[index++]));
});

// Run 20 times, index starts at 20
// index = 0 << You need this.
$('.answers').each(function() {
    // randorder[index++] << index = 20, doesn't exist in your array, hence undefined
    $(this).addClass('answer' + (randorder[index++]));
});
```

What I was attempting to show is that you are using the same index, but never resetting it to 0, so you are constantly counting up from 0 through both your iterations of 20. The correct solution is to the add index = 0 before the second .each(..);